# Objective C : change label with segue variable between two views with same controller

Tags: ios, objective-c

I have a main view controller that processes data. I want to send this data and display it in a modal view without using another controller.

I have something like this in my controller:

```
NSString *myData = @"something";
[self performSegueWithIdentifier:@"MySegue" sender:myData];
```

I have created a new view in the storyboard and a "Present modally" segue between them. I have created a label in the new view that I would like to change to display the content of myData.

But since there is no controller for this view I can't find a way to link the label to the data. Every advice I find (like PrepareForSegue) is for a two controllers configuration.

Comment: could you please more specific so i can help you.Are you trying to change value of label on new view controller when segue performed?

Comment: Yes this is exactly what I want !

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Every scene (at least every scene that you want to update custom controls on) should have its own view controller. If you create a scene without a custom view controller class specified, it will still instantiate a standard `UIViewController` object. Without a custom view controller, you have no way of updating the label on that destination scene.

The [standard answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5210535/passing-data-between-view-controllers%E2%80%8C%E2%80%8B) applies here. Give that destination scene its own view controller class, define a custom property in that destination class, have `prepareForSegue` in the source controller update that custom property in the destination controller, and have the destination view controller's `viewDidLoad` update the label on the basis of that custom property you set.